# Anime.js stagger offset issue using hexagons: works on 1080px width, but not any other resolution

Tags: javascript, html, css, anime.js

I'm new-ish to web development, and trying to learn by modifying a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bAwEj_mSzOs) to make a staggered hexagonal grid that fades out when clicked with anime.js.

Here is a gif of it working as intended (width 1080px):
[image: functional hexagon stagger effect]

But as soon as I change the screen width (1600px, for example):
[image: Bottom left corner begins acting up]

The bottom left corner appears sort of disconnected with the rest of the tiles, which detracts from the effect. I'd like to make it not do this, but am not sure what the issue with anime.js is here. How could I make this work as intended?

Here's the code I'm running:

[Codepen for convenience](https://codepen.io/minater247/pen/MWBBeRr)

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./homepage.css">
    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- hexagonal grid -->
        <div class="containercontainer">
            <div class="hexagoncontainer">
                  <div id="hexagons"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./homepage.js"></script>


    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* CSS Document */

@keyframes background-pan {
  from {
    background-position: 0% center;
  }

  to {
    background-position: -200% center;
  }
}

body {
    width:100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.containercontainer {
    animation: background-pan 10s linear infinite;
    background: linear-gradient(
        to right,
        rgb(98,0,234),
        rgb(236,64,122),
        rgb(98,0,234)
    );

    background-size: 200%;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: -75px;
    margin-right: -200px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.hexagoncontainer {
    --s: 100px;  /* size of a hexagon */
    --m: 1px;   /* space between each heaxgon */
    --r: calc(var(--s)*3*1.1547/2 + 4*var(--m));
    display:flex;
}

#hexagons div {
  width: var(--s);
  height: calc(var(--s)*1.1547); 
  margin: var(--m);
  display: inline-block;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 25%, 0% 75%, 50% 100%, 100% 75%, 100% 25%, 50% 0%);
  margin-bottom: calc(var(--m) - var(--s)*0.32); 
}

#hexagons::before {
  content: "";
  width: calc(var(--s)/2 + var(--m));
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  shape-outside: repeating-linear-gradient(     
                  transparent 0 calc(var(--r) - 3px),      
                  #fff        0 var(--r));
}

.hexagon {
    background-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
}
```

Annnd finally, the javascript:

```
const wrapper = document.getElementById("hexagons");

let columns = 0, rows = 0, toggled = false;

const hexagonOnClick = index => {
    toggled = !toggled;

    anime({
        targets: ".hexagon",
        opacity: toggled ? 0 : 1,
        delay: anime.stagger(50, {
            grid: [columns, rows],
            from: index
        })
    });
}

const createTile = index => {
    const tile = document.createElement("div");

    tile.classList.add("hexagon");

    tile.onclick = e => hexagonOnClick(index);

    tile.style.opacity = toggled ? 0 : 1;

    return tile;
}

const createTiles = quantity => {
    Array.from(Array(quantity)).map((tile, index) => {
        wrapper.appendChild(createTile(index));
    });
}

const createGrid = () => {
    wrapper.innerHTML = "";

    const size = document.body.clientWidth > 800 ? 100 : 50;

    columns = Math.floor(document.body.clientWidth / size) + 2;
    rows = Math.floor(document.body.clientHeight / size) + 2;

    wrapper.style.setProperty("--columns", columns)
    wrapper.style.setProperty("--rows", rows);
    wrapper.style.setProperty("--hexagonSize", size);

    createTiles(columns * rows);
}

createGrid();

window.onresize = () => createGrid();
```

Any help on this is much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer myself by tinkering around more!

The issue was here in the CSS:

```
.containercontainer {
    animation: background-pan 10s linear infinite;
    background: linear-gradient(
        to right,
        rgb(98,0,234),
        rgb(236,64,122),
        rgb(98,0,234)
    );

    background-size: 200%;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: -75px;
    margin-right: -200px; /* the problem */
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
}
```

The margin allowed room for plenty of hexagons in the odd rows, but in the even rows cut them short by one. By adding a little more space (adjusting the right margin to -220px), it now works as intended!

Comment: FYI I suspect there will also be future readers who misinterpret this answer. Almost the whole answer is about the problem, including a giant code block of the broken code rather than fixed code. The actual solution is only one tiny phrase at the end. I suggest rephrasing/restructuring/reformatting your answer to highlight the actual solution.